# How to add AdMob as item of ListView in Android ?

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have a question about Google Admob (referenced libraries GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar) .
My question :

1. I have a ListView about Football and now I want to add Admob as a item of my ListView
2. For example:

   - Item 1
   - Item 2
   - Item 3
   - <---------------Banner Advertisement of google -----> using Admob
   - Item 4
   - Item 5
   - Item 6
   - <---------------Banner Advertisement of google ------> ..........

**How to add Admob into ListView as a item of ListView** - 
Does everyone known that. 
Please help me...
Thank you very much !

Comment: See if this help [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedding-admob-adverts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do that and you are asking to have your account banned...

From: http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/policies-tips-developers-publishers

> The number of ads on a single page should not exceed one if the ad is
>   fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, there
>   should be a maximum of one ad on the top and one ad on the bottom, and
>   both ads should not appear on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the note - I was trying to do the same thing, Think I'll settle for just a single ad at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I don't know if Google policy changed but there are many apps that use this design pattern now e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Reddit is fun etc. My guess is they comply roughly to this policy by still only displaying roughly one ad per page by spacing the ads several elements apart.

Answer (score 0):

You probably found a solution, but anyway, please check this [link](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html) 
http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html
it explains how you can display several ads in a listview.
You should not show more than one ad per page view; thus, the idea is that, if your regular list can show 8 items per page, then insert your ad every 8th, 16th, 24th... and so on.
I hope this helps.